# managing AWS SQS and DLQ

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Scenario :

create a lambda and it will be triggered whenever a message comes to SQS(let's assume SQS-A). The lambda (written in python)is responsible for sending the incoming payload to the another endpoint.

The problem is, whenever the target endpoint or server is down, I was trying to place it into the another SQS (let's assume SQS-B), if other exceptions comes than placing it into Deal Letter Queue.

Here I want to two things.

1. If ConnectionError (it is the python exception says which says endpoint is down) comes I want to stop the the SQS-A(there is no point to run the lambda as the target server is down).

(or)

2. As whenever I get this error I am sending it to the SQS-B, I want the SQS-B to be triggered for when the first request comes and it should check if still there is a connection error, it has to trigger after 10 minutes, and again check, if exception persists trigger after 30 minutes, like this
   I want to increment the time up to 4 hours and after that check/trigger the lambda every 4 hours. If there is no exception then it should read all the messages in the SQS-B.

Help me how to achieve any one of the approach or recommend any other better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a complex architecture due to a simple problem (the target not being available). Try not to over-complicate things.

I would recommend:

- Have the originating system send the message to an **Amazon SNS topic**
- The topic triggers a Lambda function

  - If it successfully processes the message, no further action required
  - If the remote endpoint is not available, put the message into an **Amazon SQS queue** for later processing
- Use Amazon CloudWatch Events to **trigger a Lambda function every *n* minutes** that grabs any messages in the queue and tries to send them again. If the remote endpoint is still down, it exits and the process will be attempted again *n* minutes later.

  - Probably worth also sending an email to an Admin if a message gets older than a few hours.

If you *must* send the original message to an SQS queue, then you could do as you described... send to Queue-A first, which triggers a Lambda function. If the endpoint is down, Lambda sends the message to Queue-B for later processing. However, only process from Queue-B every *n* minutes (rather than trying to make each individual message have its own delay timer).

Comment: Hi @John Rotenstein, thanks for the response. For example, there are 1000 messages in Queue-B, and it triggers every _n_ minutes, if the target is not available there is no point to trigger 1000 messages from Queue-B. Is there any way to stop from the first message, if the target is down and try after _n_ minutes. I believe if _n_ message available in  _Queue_ and lambda triggered to it, then it will definitely call _n_ times the lambda function and it is not necessary in my case, as we know that in the first call itself the target is down.

Comment: To clarify: The Lambda job that triggers every _n_ minutes would grab the first message and attempt to send it. If it fails, the function simply exits. It will then be triggered after another _n_ minutes and it would try the same thing. At worst, it only tries one message before exiting. If the first message worked, however, it would continue processing messages until it fails again or Queue B is empty.

Comment: The lambda maximum configured timeout is 5 min. With in that time I can't process thousands of messages. That is the reason, I attached lambda to SQS, so that whenever the message comes SQS, the lambda will be triggered and process the message. This is the case I am talking about, after _n_ minutes, will enable/attach the lambda to SQS, so that it can process. But the problem is for all the messages in the SQS, it will trigger the lambda that many times, even the first message is not processed.

Comment: My suggestion was that every message is attempted initially (wasteful, yes, but that's how it is). If it fails, it goes into Queue B. Then, Queue B is tried every _n_ minutes. If the Queue B lambda function times-out, then the messages will be sent with the next invocation after _n_ minutes. (So, set _n_ to 5 minutes!) Do not link Lambda directly to Queue B. Rather, process it via the "every _n_ minutes" lambda function.

Comment: Well, this case will happens very rarely, i.e., if the lambda deployed early, before the the target server is not deployed or any other problem which occurred in target server, makes it down. So, running the cron job every _n_ minutes is a proper solution, even it happens once in a blue moon ?

Comment: Definitely. Lambda is only charged per 100ms, so you won't notice it.