# Sending a Message with a Timer to an Amazon SQS Standard Queue is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

In my aws standard queue I'm trying to schedule message.
I have set the `Delay delivery` as 10 minutes.
As per documentation, 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-send-message-with-timer.html
message should not visible in queue until delay time. but my message is immediately available to process. 
Is there any other configurations required to set on my queue.

[image]

Even though I have scheduled my message I can see it in my queue messages available section.

[image]

Can any one help me to understand this scenario.

Comment: What do you mean by "my message is immediately available to process". Did your application call `ReceiveMessage()` and receive that message within the 10-minute period?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Sorry, I didn't mentioned it clearly. Now I have updated my question with the snapshot.
I mean I'm able to see the message in the messages available section and also when I polled for the messges I'm able to view the message immediately.
And I have also tried to trigger my standard queue with a lambda function to process the newly arrived message to the queue.
When I see my lambda function logs I found that the message I have scheduled was immediately received by the lambda function and processed.
I'm not able to get what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to reproduce your situation:

- An Amazon SQS queue
- An AWS Lambda function triggered by the SQS queue
- Sent a message with a delay
- Result: Lambda immediately processed the message

The ability for SQS to trigger Lambda was [added in June 2018](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-adds-amazon-simple-queue-service-to-supported-event-sources/), so it is relatively new. The [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon SQS - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) documentation does not make mention of Delays.

Therefore, it's either the way that it operates (but isn't documented) or an incorrect behavior.

Comment: Thank you very much..That's a great clarification for me. Even though I have disabled my lambda function trigger, I'm able to see my scheduled message in `Messages Available` section, 
Does this means if I give a `ReceiveMessage` call from my application, then also I'm able to get the message?
Can you please tell me how can I apply my timers efficiently.

Comment: What is the use-case you are trying to achieve? When you say "I'm trying to schedule message", what are you doing with the messages? There might be a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: There are two things I need to achieve:
1. I will get messages to my queue which can be processed immediately

2. Messages which should be scheduled for a given time and should remain in the queue until the scheduled time,
and should be available to process only at the scheduled time.
Since its allowing me a max of 15 min to schedule a message (and not a future date or time), I have scheduled it to be processed after 10 minutes from now. However, the message gets processed immediately.

What is the best platform in `AWS` that I can use to achieve these.

Comment: How do you distinguish which messages should get delayed? Does the message sender call the AWS SQS API directly, passing in the desired (non-functional) delay? If so, why doesn't the sender simply send the message directly, or call Lambda directly? Also, what volume of messages are you expecting (eg messages per minute)? Is the 15 minute maximum delay sufficient? Finally, what are you doing in the Lambda function? I ask this because there might be a alternative/better approach.

Comment: I am building an app which requires notifications to be sent to a user. (Using lambda function for the same)
In case there is a technical glitch or for some reason the message cudnt be sent to the end user, I want to retry the function every 10 minutes(in this case) till I get a success response.

Also, I want to provide notification subscription option and in few countries the regulations require us to follow strict timelines i.e. send messages only at the timing selected by the user.

For implementing both the scenarios, I want to queue a message and send it at the desired timing.

Comment: This sounds very similar to [python - managing AWS SQS and DLQ - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441240/managing-aws-sqs-and-dlq/51443299#51443299). There is a maximum 15 minute delay, so that will not meet your requirement. You will need to build a different solution for sending in _strict timelines_.

Comment: John, Thank you very much for your inputs. I will check for other solutions.